# How do I read mongo data in java from a database just created?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a Java program that successfully creates a mongo database; after the program runs the code to insert the data, I can use the mongo command line program to view the data.

I am trying to write a little test code that reads that data, finds max values, and the like. But I can't seem to get 'find()' to work. I have the following:

```
  MongoClient readClient = new MongoClient();
  DB db = readClient.getDB("x");
  DBCollection readings = db.getCollection("y"); 

  DBCursor cursor = readings.find();
  DBObject element = cursor.curr();
```

The database x and the collection y are there, I can see them from the command line program. But if I put a breakpoint after the `cursor.curr()` statement, the element is null.

The previous version of the code used the same DB and DBCollection objects used to create the database, but thought perhaps that meant there was a cursor positioned after all the records, so I created the new MongoClient on the theory that it would start at the beginning of the collection again. But it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? Is there some 'close()' or 'flush()' or something that need to include?

(corrected to say the element is null, originally stated it was the cursor)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to position the cursor an initial time before `curr()` works; `next()` does what I want instead.